# Can't play animation in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

Im trying to play GIF image, which i taken from [preloaders site](http://preloaders.net/en/circular), in my frame:

```
class TestFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        self.animation = wx.animate.AnimationCtrl(self, pos=(40,40), size=(24, 24), name="AnimationCtrl")
        self.animation.LoadFile("./gui/icons/preloader.gif", wx.animate.ANIMATION_TYPE_GIF)
        self.animation.Play()

        size = (310, 150)
        self.SetSize(size)
        self.icon = wx.Icon('./gui/icons/app.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
        self.SetIcon(self.icon)
        self.Show()
```

In result ill will see only all gif (its looks like just imported image at frame). What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it worked fine on my computer. I have python 2.7 and wxPython 3.0.
If you still haven't solved your problem try using this code:

```
import wx.animate

class TestFrame2( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Testing!", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = ( 300,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.RESIZE_BORDER )
        self.m_animCtrl1 = wx.animate.AnimationCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.animate.NullAnimation, ( 40,40 ), ( -1,-1 ), wx.animate.AC_DEFAULT_STYLE )
        self.m_animCtrl1.LoadFile( u"img.GIF" )
        self.m_animCtrl1.Play()
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = wx.App()
    TestFrame2(None)
    App.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually using Py3 and wxPython Phoenix, but this code got it working for me.

```
import wx
from wx.adv import Animation, AnimationCtrl

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)

        self.animation = AnimationCtrl(self, pos=(40,40), size=(24, 24), name="AnimationCtrl")
        self.animation.LoadFile("animated.gif")
        self.animation.Play()

        size = (400, 400)
        self.SetSize(size)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App()
frame = TestFrame(None, -1, "Test gif")
app.MainLoop()
```

For wxPython I think you need to use a GIFAnimationCtrl instead of AnimationCtrl.  I don't have an environment to test it though.  [Here is the relevant documentation.](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl-class.html)  It's unfortunately pretty sparse.

**Even better**
Blog post with an example.  This should give you something to build off of. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216673/wxpython-animated-gif

Comment: Has there been any windows installer released for wxPython Phoenix?

Comment: Not that I know of.  However the nightly builds are extremely easy to install.  Just go to http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ and scroll down to the bottom.  Then either get the win32 for 32bit systems, or win_amd64 for 64bit systems.  Then I just used pip to install it. `pip install name_of_file_you_downloaded.whl`